# Exoplayer show thumbnail while loading

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video, exoplayer

My ExoPlayer buffers about 1 second before it starts playing. Instead of showing a blackscreen, I would like it to show the first frame of the video.

What I have tried is putting an ImageView on top of the ExoPlayer, and load it in there using the following code:

```
try (MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever()) {
    retriever.setDataSource(videoURL, new HashMap<String, String>());
    Bitmap image = retriever.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    if (image != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the video starts playing, I just make this ImageView invisible and also replace it's content with null for better performance.

This does work, but it causes severe performance issues. I'm not sure why, but it does. It's impossible to use this in production, the app is lagging extremely when I add this.

So how can I do this instead? Is there maybe even a built in function of ExoPlayer that we can use (I didn't find anything)?

It might be worth to mention that all videos are pre-cached, so usually the first frame SHOULD be somewhere saved in the ExoPlayer cache.

Answer (score 0):

Sir use glide library its easy to load thumbnail more than MediaMetadataRetriever

```
  long thumb = getLayoutPosition()*1000;
  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(thumb);
  Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).apply(options).into(mThumb);
```